# How to efficiently query all records of timestamp.second == 5 in the orderbook table

Tags: time-series, timestamp, dolphindb

How can I efficiently query all the records of timestamp.second == 5 in the orderbook table in dolphindb? For example, the records of timestamp 00:00:05, 00:01:05 00:02:05. 
can the following statement work?
select * from tick where timestamp.second == 5?

Answer (score 0):

There is a "secondOfMinute" to get the number of seconds, such as:

```py
select * from tick where secondOfMinute(timestamp) == 5
```